# Moving wikipages inside the same wiki pages library?

Tags: 2010, wiki, enterprise-wiki

By default the option to move to another location is disabled in wiki pages library.
In our wiki page library there are many folders and it should be possible for normal users to move from one folder to another one.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I just checked and send to other location is disabled, I tried by enablling a custom send to Location, on advanced settings, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The send to location does not work on wiki pages library, but there is the possibility to move items from one folder to another inside the same site

Note: [Publishing feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518) needs to be enabled on site collection level and site level

1. Go to **Site Settings**
2. Go to **Content and Structure**
3. Select wiki pages to be moved with tick box to the left of the page name
4. Actions > Move
5. Select the destination folder from the picker tree
6. Select <kbd>OK</kbd> to move the pages to the target folder

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to do that is to edit the page, copy the contents and paste them in a new page in another folder or to use the Content and Structure to move the pages;)

Comment: Indeed the content and structure is a quick solution, but we dont want the normal users to be able to see master pages, style library, etc, etc,

Comment: @EstebanV This is a serious drawback of this approach but there appears to be no other way to cleanly move wiki pages around. Perhaps this will be addressed in a future version of SP. For those looking to migrate or overhaul site content then Content and Structure is the way.